# Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you.

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-collection, pages, out-of-the-box

I am root site collection administrator for the site below:

```
http://Myapp/_layouts/15/settings.aspx
```

But still I could not view any of out of the box sharepoint pages like settings.aspx and see this message:

```
Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you.
```

What I need to do more?

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Comment: chrome and IE, same result !!

Comment: Are you a member of any of the Visitor/Member/Owner groups in that site collection root web?

Answer (score 0):

Hit the following URL and Enter Credential again.

```
http:/Myapp/_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true
```

Comment: still have same problem.. I got access denied: http:/Myapp/_layouts/15/AccessDenied.aspx?Source=http%3A%2F%2Fabc%3A2010%2F_layouts%2F15%2Fsettings%2Easpx

Answer (score 0):

Try with "Private window" with re entering password

**OR** try below steps

1. Start | Run | regedit
2. Navigate to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE | SYSTEM | CurrentControlSet | Control | Lsa
3. Right-click and create a new DWORD labelled: DisableLoopbackCheck and assign a value of 1.
4. Reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check if Site Collection is not on read-only mode? Are you using SharePoint online or on-premise?